# Extract Complex URLs From Text

Tags: php, regex

The text contains URLs like
https://www.yyyy.com/blablabla/https://www.foofoofoofoofoo/loremlorem/lorem/https:www.textext.net/

They're all adjacent. Regex didn't help. I'd like to solve it like that;
Search for https://www 
If matches then extract (first 10 characters only) to an array.

Comment: Why aren't there at least line breaks after each item?  Add line breaks the explode the string by `\n` and loop through.

Comment: I didn't prepare the text. It contains up to 500 URLs like that without line breaks.

Comment: Are you in contact with whoever created that output or wrote the script/app/whatever that makes the output?  I can't understand why anyone would do it that way.  a line break, a comma, a |, anything would help you.

Comment: Yes, an explode on http would work.  It's just silly the way it is.

Comment: Let us know what regex did you try

Comment: '#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be:

```
<?php
$str = "https://www.yyyy.com/blablabla/https://www.foofoofoofoofoo/loremlorem/lorem/https:www.textext.net/";
    //add an space to explode it easily:     
     $my_str = preg_replace("*https:*", " https:", $str);
     $values = explode(' ', $my_str);    
     var_dump($values);
?>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
         //First separate the url string:
 $str = "https://www.yyyy.com/blablabla/https://www.foofoofoofoofoo/loremlorem/lorem/https:www.textext.net/https://youtube.com/channels/uniqueID/about/foofoofoo/foo";
 $breakpoint = "https:";
 //add an space to explode it easily:    
 $my_str = preg_replace("*" . $breakpoint . "/?/?*", " ", $str);
 $values = explode(' ', $my_str);    
 var_dump($values);

 //Now, foreach url you can perform whatever you want:
 $end = "about/";
 $a = array();
 foreach($values as $value){
    if( preg_match("*" . $end . "*",$value) ){
        //split string in parts:
        $val = preg_split("*" . $end . "*",$value);
        $a[] = $val[0];
    }
 }

var_dump($a);
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to write a regex grab spesific parts of a link? youtube.com/channels/uniqueID/about/foofoofoo/foo How can I extract only this part www.youtube.com/channels/uniqueID/ between https: and about

Answer (score 0):

According to the text you given as sample, I think preg_split is your best bet:

```
$urls = preg_split('/(http){1}s?\:(\/\/)?/i', $text);
```

$urls will be your desired array of splitted url's. Test it on several of your full text & let us know

Comment: Didn't worked.
Is it possible to write a regex grab spesific parts of a link?
https://www.youtube.com/channels/uniqueID/about/foofoofoo/foo

How can I extract only this part
www.youtube.com/channels/uniqueID/

between https: and about

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/038e70049432593dcb2b48874ebc66835ed05e82 it works ... Remove g from the end of pattern - PHP don't understand this modifier

Comment: About other parts of URL extracting - yes it ofcourse possible if you can find a pattern. Example - only domain name or upto 2 slashes after domain or a common keyword like 'about' , uniqueid etc. finding the proper pattern is the trick - though it's not possible always, at least not in your sample text of url's